# help can I recover ltc sent to a btc address

Tags: transactions, litecoin, ledger-hardware-wallet, cross-chain-recovery

Im super new like a lot of people. I have a nano s ledger and I attetpted to send ltc from coinbase to the ledger only to realize I used the btc address on my ledger. Is this recoverable?

Answer (score 1):

If you send some cryptocurrency to an address of another type of cryptocurrency (with a valid address in its own format), you may have lost your money (if you don't own that address) in the source cryptocurrency you made the transaction from.

A way you could recover the money is to make another transaction from the new address to another address you own, like the old one. However, as this is still a wrong transaction, it could still have issues getting confirmed, and it may even come with a higher fee.

Comment: Not true.......

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden What did I say wrong? 
[edit] I said "If you send criptocurrency to an address... ...you don't own" I was assuming that he sent the amount to someone else and not to an address of his own, I'll correct

Answer (score 1):

Since the bitcoin address entered by mistake and litecoin address intended are derived from same mnemonic words, simple scanning the mnemonic into a litecoin wallet that scans a bit of the HD-key tree for balance, should work.

You can try entering your mnemonic at https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and playing with the values. If you fix the purpose to 44 and coin to 0, changing the values of 'account' and 'internal/external' should reveal your bitcoin address in question in the list at the bottom. Once you do, you will know its private key and should be able to then scan it in a litecoin wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the derivation for segwit address for Bitcoin and Litecoin are more or less the same. Try importing the private key of the BTC ledger address in an LTC wallet.

They changed the 3 address to an M address because of this. However, these adresses are still valid.

See this guide:
https://litecointalk.io/t/accidentally-sent-litecoin-to-my-bitcoin-wallet-address/8826/19